# external js file is not working in safari app mode in ipad3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, iphone-5, ipad-3

In footer we are giving

```
<script src="/js/general.js"></script>
```

file but in app mode of (ipad3, iphone5) that file is not working.
Any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the full url of your `js` file, like,

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/js/general.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the type="text/javascript" in the script tag.